# Supremum of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I encountered this question in a grad-level exam. i hope somebody could help.

we have to choose one correct option.

Let $a_n = \sin (\pi/n).$ For the sequence $a_1, a_2,...$ the supremum is:

$a)$ $0$ & it is attained

$b)$ $0$ & it is not attained

$c)$ $1$ & it is attained

$d)$ $1$ & it is not attained

this sine function would oscillate b/w 0 and 1. but it doesn't converge to 1. so shouldn't the answer be d?

Comment: Now surely you don't mean all of that

Comment: Ramit: And now the real mystery is: which parts of the accepted answer eluded you when you tried to solve the question?

Comment: Wow. And I guess this tactics is also why you posted your two other questions?

Comment: Scared of leaving your previous comment apparent? Interesting...

Comment: This is actually even more interesting: you received a notification that it is better if you conceal that your motive for asking some questions is not to get some answer to a math problem but to grab some reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $c$.

Note that $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$ for all real $x$. So $\sup\{\sin(\pi/n):n\in\mathbb{N}\} \leq \sup\{\sin(x):x\in\mathbb{R}\} = 1$. Also, we see $a_2 = \sin(\pi/2) = 1$, and so $\sup\{\sin(\pi/n):n\in\mathbb{N}\} \geq 1$.

Comment: okay, got it, we are just concerned with upper bound irrespective of that being convergent value.

Comment: @Ramit: Correct. When you're asked to compute the supremum of a sequence (in this case $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for $a_n = \sin(\pi/n)$), you're really finding the supremum (a.k.a. least upper bound) of the *set* $A := \{a_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. It *may* be the case that $\sup A = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ (for example, if $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an increasing sequence), but it doesn't have to be (and the sup will be defined in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ even if the sequence diverges).